# Why my code loop infinite submit and not echo $post name test_value?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Why my code loop infinite submit and not echo $post name test_value ?

How can i do that ?

.......................................................................

```
<form id="fid" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test_value" value="ON">            
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">   
</form>
<input type="text" id="check_submit"/>


<script>
var check_submit_val = document.getElementById("check_submit").value;
if(check_submit_val != '')
{
}
else
{
    document.getElementById('check_submit').value = '1';
    document.createElement('form').submit.call(document.getElementById('fid'));
}
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo $_POST["test_value"];
}
?>
```

Comment: <form id="fid" method="POST"/> - you are closing form tag immediately which is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when id `check_submit` is empty ,it will submit the form so you r calling the current file so it will check the id `check_sumit` has some value ,so it was reload the page still empty ,so will get infinity loop.
**So I advice you to set the `check_submit` value after submit by $_POST**

Change it

```
<form id="fid" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test_value" value="ON">            
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">   
</form>
<input type="text" id="check_submit"/>
```

To like this

```
<form id="fid" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test_value" value="ON">            
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">   
</form>
<input type="text" id="check_submit" value="<?= isset($_POST["test_value"]) ? $_POST["test_value"] :''; ?>"> //set check_submit value if happen submit form
```

Comment: but `<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    echo $_POST["test_value"];
}
?>`  not work , how can i do that ?

Comment: That is ,you are calling form submit by create new form element! so there is no any name submit element so that it's doesn't work!!! Change like this `<?php if(isset($_POST)) { echo $_POST["test_value"]; } ?>` will work